# Retrieve Custom Workflows Info

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, powershell

Via SharePoint Designer it's possible to verify all Site Collection Workflows (on the Workflows List) grouped by type.

How can I via Powershell retrieve all that info displayed in the SPD Workflows List?

I already attempt via:

- **SPSite.RootWeb.Workflows**: Only WF files
- **SPList.WorflowAssociations**: need to iterate through all the Lists and not all info is available
- **Retrieving directly DB** info from [WorkflowAssociation] or [AllDocs] tables and anywhere I can get a full detailed info as in that SPD List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterates through all Web Application Site Collections (or one only) and for each Subsite retrieved the Custom Workflows (List Workflows - if exist) 
Note: The custom workflows data is retrieved from the xoml config file (Eg. MyCustomWF.xoml.wfconfig.xml) metadata and inner xml properties.

Possible retrieved WF metadata:

- Title
- Description
- Association Base ID
- Workflow Type
- Web URL
- Author
- Modified on